# Sanitizing DB inputs with XSLT

Tags: sql, xslt, input, sanitize, apostrophe

I've been looking for a method to strip my XML content of apostrophes (') since my DBMS is complaining of receiving those.

I need

```
<name> Jim O'Connor</name>
```

to become:

```
<name> Jim O''Connor</name>
```

By looking at the example described [here](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6075563.html), that is supposed to replace `'` with `''`, I constructed the following script:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="sqlApostrophe">
        <xsl:param name="string" />
        <xsl:variable name="apostrophe">'</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($string,$apostrophe)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($string,$apostrophe), $apostrophe,$apostrophe)"
            disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            <xsl:call-template name="sqlApostrophe">
              <xsl:with-param name="string"
              select="substring-after($string,$apostrophe)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"
            disable-output-escaping="yes" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="sqlApostrophe">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE: it works fine**

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1) What process and what language are you using to perform the DB insert?
2) Could the the language from question #1 be used to pre-process the single quotes?

Comment: I invoke a SQL Server stored procedure, with a bunch of XPath expressions as its parameters

Comment: Your stored procedure is buggy. You should fix the problem there, not in the XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in your last template. As dacracot [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827824/sanitizing-db-inputs-with-xslt/2828100#2828100), `xsl:apply-templates` does not take a `name` attribute. To call a named template, you'd use `xsl:call-template`.

If you want to apply your SQL escaping to all text nodes, you could try replacing your last template with something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="sqlApostrophe">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, why `disable-output-escaping`? If the text contains special characters (`<`, `>`, `&`), you'll get malformed XML as the output.

Comment: I tried using that instead of my broken template, but still no successs

Comment: How does it fail? Perhaps you could post a more complete example. Here's what works for me. Stylesheet: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vV0F2nYZ Input: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J5wLF9B0 Live result: http://www.w3.org/2000/06/webdata/xslt?xslfile=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fi%3DvV0F2nYZ&xmlfile=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fi%3DJ5wLF9B0&transform=Submit (View Source to see the result).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues syntactically...

1. You can't have a name attribute on an apply-templates tag.
2. Your xpath, "node()|@*", is ambiguous.

Have you run this through a debugger?  I would suggest Oxygen.